# Removing inline CSS using div

Tags: html, css

I have this table containing submit buttons:

```
<table style="border: 0; width: 15%">
    <tr style="background-color: transparent">
        <td style="border: 0">
            <form action="displayevalform" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Go Back">
            </form>
        </td>                       
        <td style="border: 0">
            <form action="evaluate" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Done">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works, but to adhere to good practice, I decided to remove the inline CSS and place the `<table>` in a `<div>`:

```
<style>
.tblreset table {
    border: 0;
    width: 15%;
}

.tblreset tr {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.tblreset td {
    border: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="tblreset">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="displayevalform" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go Back">
                </form>
            </td>                       
            <td>
                <form action="evaluate" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Done">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This no longer works. Is there something wrong with my CSS syntax?

Comment: are you adding the `<style>` at `<head>` section?

Comment: It is in a `layout.css` file, which is referenced in the `<head>`.

Comment: check reference is ok

Comment: Yes, `<link href>` is okay, since all other styles are applied. Just not the `.tblreset` styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The `layout.css` is from a template and contains styles for `table`, `tr`, `th`, `td`. I figured it must be conflicting with my `tblreset` styles, so I just put them in a separate `table.css` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some css properties, that seems to be better the change:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .tblreset table {
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        width: 25%;
      }

      .tblreset tr {
        background-color: green;
      }

     .tblreset td {
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="tblreset">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form action="displayevalform" method="post">
              <input type="submit" value="Go Back">
            </form>
          </td>                       
          <td>
            <form action="evaluate" method="post">
              <input type="submit" value="Done">
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```